# Error while setting adapter for list-view Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I am getting a weird error while setting up my adapter for `listview` in `Android`. I am developing a chat application, when i send any message it appears in listview, but when i try to receive the message it takes me to `Catch-block` in `FutureTask` class

I am using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to let my adapter know of any change i am creating in the adapter.

**My code is as follows**

```
private void addNewMessage(MessageItems m) {

    if(MainActivity.mymessage)
    {
    messages.add(m);
    }else if(MainActivity.mymessage == false)
    {
        messages.add(m);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    getListView().setSelection(messages.size()-1);

}

**Code of Adapter**

public class AwesomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<MessageItems> mMessages;



    public AwesomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessageItems> messages) {
        super();
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mMessages = messages;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mMessages.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return mMessages.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        MessageItems message = (MessageItems) this.getItem(position);

        ViewHolder holder; 
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.sms_row, parent, false);
            holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());

        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.message.getLayoutParams();
        //check if it is a status message then remove background, and change text color.
        if(message.isStatusMessage())
        {
            holder.message.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            holder.message.getResources().getColor(R.color.textFieldColor);
            //holder.message.setTextColor(R.color.textFieldColor);
        }
        else
        {       
            //Check whether message is mine to show green background and align to right
            if(message.isMine())
            {
                holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_green);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            }
            //If not mine then it is from sender to show orange background and align to left
            else
            {
                holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            }
            holder.message.setLayoutParams(lp);
            holder.message.getResources().getColor(R.color.textFieldColor);
            //holder.message.setTextColor(R.color.textColor);   
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView message;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        //Unimplemented, because we aren't using Sqlite.
        return position;
    }
```

**In FutureTask class it takes me to the following try-catch block when i try to set adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**

```
public void run() {
    if (state != NEW ||
        !UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, runnerOffset,
                                     null, Thread.currentThread()))
        return;
    try {
        Callable<V> c = callable;
        if (c != null && state == NEW) {
            V result;
            boolean ran;
            try {
                result = c.call();
                ran = true;
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                result = null;
                ran = false;
                setException(ex);
            }
            if (ran)
                set(result);
        }
    } finally {
        // runner must be non-null until state is settled to
        // prevent concurrent calls to run()
        runner = null;
        // state must be re-read after nulling runner to prevent
        // leaked interrupts
        int s = state;
        if (s >= INTERRUPTING)
            handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt(s);
    }
}
```

I know the problem somewhere lies in setting up the adapter for listview, i need to update it as i get a new message, but i am unable to get it fixed. Your help would be appreciated

Comment: it is all because serial upvoting(you have been flagged, again, so you should expect ban for few days) ... and about question: you cannot touch views from non UI thread(i'm pretty sure that it is written in the exception) ... asked so many times here ...

Comment: I am doing it in a UI thread

Comment: SendMessage function is written in a UI thread. Please have a look at it

Comment: I am too naive to understand the problem here, can you provide me an example here?

Comment: do not call addNewMessage from non UI thread  (fx do not call it from doInBackground of AsyncTask) .... end of story ...